# why i get "type mismatch" error in the code below in excel-vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem.

```
kwota_wplaty_temp = CDbl(.tb_kwota_wplaty.value)
```

kwota_wplaty_temp is double type.
.tb_kwota_wplaty.value is a textbox.

thanks for the answers.

Comment: Remove the `.` in `CDbl(.tb_kwota_wplaty.value)` and try again.

Comment: Post the full code block please

Comment: Whatever is in `tb_kwota_wplaty` can't be converted to a Double using your regional settings.

Comment: i have a solution. Instead CDbl i put val and that works fine. thanks for the answer

Comment: Textboxes always return strings - even if you fill them with numbers.